# RSpec - spec fails when trying to call method on initialized attribute

Tags: ruby, rspec, initialization

Here is the code for my specs and class:

```
describe Game do

  before(:each) do
    @game = Factory.build(:game)
  end

  describe '#no_books?' do
    it 'should return true if books attribute is empty' do
      @game.stub(:books).and_return([])
      @game.no_books?.should be_true
    end

    it 'should return false if books attribute is present' do
      @game.no_books?.should be_false
    end
  end

end


class Game

  attr_reader :books

  def initialize
    @books = parse_books
  end

  def no_books?
    @books.empty?
  end

  protected

  def parse_books
    # return books
  end

end
```

I then get a friendly spec failure message:

```
Game#no_books? should return true if books attribute is empty
     Failure/Error: @game.no_books?.should be_true
       expected false to be true
```

It's as if that method is getting called before the attribute books get initialized with a value. Can someone explain to me what's going here?

Comment: You should be wary about writing tests like this that deal with the internal workings of the object. These tend to be fragile (if it does the same thing, but in a different way, then tests will fail when they shouldn't, or fail when they should pass). In most cases, I think it is rarely worth while to stub the object being tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `no_books?` implementation is using the instance variable directly in its check, bypassing your stub. If you change `no_books?` to return `books.empty?`, it will call the stub instead.

If you really, *really* want to keep using the instance variable, you can set it in `@game` via `instance_variable_set` like this:

```
@game.instance_variable_set("@books", [])
```